# Where can I find a crowdsourced dataset for multi-label classification with individual participant labels?

Tags: dataset, multilabel-classification

I am looking for a dataset that has been crowdsourced, and corresponds to a multiple answer correct per question setting. I need the individual labels given by the participants from the crowd.

I have searched online (such as [here](https://www.crowdflower.com/data-for-everyone/)), but all I get is datasets where the answers have been aggregated to create a ground truth. I also found sources like [this](https://github.com/ipeirotis/Get-Another-Label), which provide such a dataset but apply to the single label case.

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Could you give an example of how such data set should look? I'm not sure I understand what is it you look for

Comment: @shakedzy I am looking for a dataset where each data point can have multiple true labels, which has also been given to a set of people for labelling their opinion of the true labels. Something like [this](https://github.com/ipeirotis/Get-Another-Label/tree/master/data/), but where multiple labels can be true. The ground truths should also be available.

Comment: You should ask in Open Data and not on DS.

Answer (score 3):

I'll think you'll find what you're looking for in [this question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/4126) on Open Data. I've checked the [Pew Research Center data](http://www.pewresearch.org/data/download-datasets/), and found [this poll](http://www.pewinternet.org/dataset/june-2016-cybersecurity-knowledge/) about cyber-security that seems to be something like what you look for.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might help where each and every type of datasets [Here](https://github.com/ChristosChristofidis/awesome-deep-learning#datasets)